# What is the error on executing apt-get (GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found)?

Tags: debian, apt-get, glibc

I have an error by installing and executing the `apt-get` (there is no package manager except `udpkg`):

```
apt-get: /usr/lib/libstd++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found (required by apt-get)
```

I have the library `/usr/lib/libstd++.so.6` there.

Comment: Oh boy, this is a bad (and fairly common) error. It sounds like you probably upgraded your system between incompatible versions of libstdc++, and in so doing, you installed an `apt-get` that is no longer binary-compatible with your C++ standard library. What mechanism did you use to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `libstdc++6`, but there are sub-versions within that and you've ended up with a 'wrong' version somehow. It's possible you have multiple sub-versions present and `libstdc++.so.6` is linking to the wrong one. If you only have the one (wrong) version, you could try downloading an rpm of the version apt-get is expecting from a website.

For any other program failing in this way I'd suggest upgrading either library or program via the package manager, or recompiling the program against the version of the library you have, but given that it's `apt`, I don't think you could do either easily..!

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191193/libstdc-so-6version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found-required-by-compiz) might help?

Comment: I cannot build a new one (I have no `gcc`, it is only an `ash` with `busybox` tools), and all that are from `debian.org` do not work.

Comment: I have the version from your post (4.4.5-8)

Comment: Hm, I don't know that much about what's provided by busybox and what isn't. Has apt-get ever worked on this box? What's the output of `strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`?

Comment: I managed it, starting from the beginning :)

Comment: Glad you fixed it! Any idea what had caused the problem?

Comment: :) may be many wild installed libraries